# Пройтись итератором по вложенной коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, итераторы, linked-list

Всем привет.
Я что-то запутался.
Есть коллекция такого типа

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<MyObject>> adj;
Как добиться Iterator<MyObject> = ;
```

Сейчас вариант

```
List<MyObject> arr[] = (LinkedList<MyObject>[]) adj.toArray();
Iterator<MyObject> i = arr[index].listIterator();
```

валиться на приведении. Т..к нельзя приводить объекты к коллекции.

Comment: adj - что такое? дополни вопрос плиз

Comment: виноват) дополнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через стримы сделать красиво:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<MyObject>> adj = ...
Iterator<MyObject> iterator = adj.stream()
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение для примера как в вопросе:

```
List<MyObject> arr[] = (LinkedList<MyObject>[]) adj.toArray(new LinkedList<?>[2]);
Iterator<MyObject> i = arr[index].listIterator();
```